# Need generic format for converting Collection to Tablerow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, transformation

I am doing transformation by reading CSV file from bucket and store in Big Query

PCollection quotes =  ....//read data and do transformation

//writing to BQ existing table which have 2 columns "source" and "quote".

```
quotes.apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(TableRow.class))
                    .via(
                        (Quote elem) ->
                            new TableRow().set("source", elem.source).set("quote", elem.quote)))
            .apply(
                BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .to(tableSpecname)
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

I need to replace code of converting PCollection to TableRow as in some cases table columns may vary, so this hardcore column names will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a `ParDo` step between your input `PCollection` and BigQuery write step and add a `DoFn` class that formats the data into `TableRow` objects the way you want.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo